# stackoverflow while calling method of parent class in subclass

Tags: java

I am trying to call the parent method in subclass. But I am getting stackoverflow error. The method name in both the class is same. If I change the method name it doesn't gives error. I am not understanding what is the reason behind it. Below is the code where I am calling display() method, in both the class which gives me stackoverflow error. If I change the name of method in any of one class it doesn't gives me error.

```
class inherit1 {

int i;
int j;
int k;

public inherit1() {
}

inherit1(int i, int j, int k) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.k = k;
}
void display() {
    System.out.println("i=" + i + "j=" + j + "k=" + k);
}
```

}

```
class in1 extends inherit1 {

int l;

in1() {
}

public in1(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
    super(i, j, k);
    this.l = l;
}

void display() {
    display();
    System.out.println("l=" + l);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    in1 i = new in1(12, 12, 12, 12);

    i.display();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
void display() {
    super.display();
    System.out.println("k=" + k);
}
```

when you are calling `display()` it calls same child method againg and again causing [`stackoverflow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).Instead you should use `super` keyword to reference parent method.

Comment: @nikalldway I have tried it and it worked for me,how you are running through cmd or IDE?

Answer (score 1):

```
void display() {
    display();
    System.out.println("k=" + k);
}
```

With this method you keep calling the same method again, which in turn leads to a StackOverFlow error because you have created an infinite loop.

This will work better:

```
void display() {
    super.display();
    System.out.println("k=" + k);
}
```

Or even this would work:

```
void display() {
    System.out.println(super.display() + ("k=" + k));
}
```

Comment: Thanks after calling super.display I am able to call both the method

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverflow Error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses
>   too deeply.

Problem is

```
void display() {
    display();  // this line is culprit you are calling the same function again and again 
    System.out.println("k=" + k);
}
```

You should call parent's display method instead

Comment: Calling parent display I wont be able to get child class method

Comment: if you don't want parent's method to be called then you should simply remove the calling of  `display()`

Comment: I wanted to call both the method of parent and subclass, having same method name.